# Control multiple MAX7219 with Node.js

Tags: node.js, memory, raspberry-pi, buffer, spi

I've been trying to control 4 MAX7219 controlled 8x8 LED arrays, totaling a 8x32 "screen". they are daisy chained, [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM0MC.jpg).

From what I've gathered, I have to send data for all of my arrays; each MAX7219 will process his own data, and the remaining data will "overflow" to the next MAX7219 to process.

This works very nicely when I address only one "row" of my screen: [First row getting and displaying the data as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olowr.jpg)

The code to achieve it is the following:

```
write = function(register, data) {
    let buf = new Buffer([register, data]);
    this.spi.write(buf, (device, buf2) => {
        let s = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
            s = s + buf[i] + " ";
    });
}
```

(from the [NPM SPI documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spi))

Writing the data:

```
write(0x01, 0x01);
write(0x01, 0x03);
write(0x01, 0x07);
write(0x01, 0x0F);
```

The issues start, when I try and write to the second row. Sending the data to the second row messes with the first one, but I just can't wrap my head around to why this happens.

```
write(0x01, 0x01);
write(0x01, 0x03);
write(0x01, 0x07);
write(0x01, 0x0F);
// Writing to the second row
write(0x02, 0x80);
write(0x02, 0xC0);
write(0x02, 0xE0);
write(0x02, 0xF0);
```

This results in a second row that looks like it should but a first row that is messed up:

[Second row OK, First row messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq3xl.jpg)

This happens with any combination of rows. The last one is OK, while the previous ones are messed up.

I don't know why other rows get all messed up, when they're not getting written to, beyond the data transfer that is confirmed to be working...

Notes: I'm using a Raspberry Pi Model B+ V1.2 with Raspbian; Node.js v8.11.1;

Comment: https://github.com/SebSchwartz/node-max7219-led-matrix/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I've seen and tried this library, and the only problem is that it only supports one single LED array (8x8), not 4 (8x32).

Also, the initialization and write method are both identical to the ones used by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying a few other repositories, (special thanks to [bitbank2](https://github.com/bitbank2/MAX7219)'s great C++ repo), and I've created an NPM Package to do exactly what I wanted it to do:

Control Multiple daisy-chained MAX7219 8x8 LED arrays, in a very simple way.

You can find the [Github repository here](https://github.com/heunetik/MAX7219-Matrix), and the [NPM Package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/max7219-matrix).